# Writing relative routes in React-router between components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Let's say I have this code in my App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Link to="/pointandclick">joc pointAndClick</Link><br />
            <Link to="/draggable">joc draggable</Link>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/pointandclick">
            <PointAndClickGame gameAnswers={['Yes', 'No']} correctAnswer="Yes" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/pointandclick1">
            <PointAndClickGame gameAnswers={['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'answer4']} correctAnswer="answer1" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/draggable">
            <DraggableGame />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

and here's PointAndClickGame.tsx

```
return (
        <div className="PointAndClickGame">
            <Menu />
                <Route path="/pointandclick"> or /pointandclick1/ depending on the first part of the url
                    <GameStart gameAnswers={props.gameAnswers} correctAnswer={props.correctAnswer} setExitGameHandler={setExitGameHandler} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/pointandclick/gameinfo"> or /pointandclick1/ depending on the first part of the url
                    <GameInfo/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/pointandclick/gamefinish"> or /pointandclick1/ depending on the first part of the url
                    <GameFinish/>
                </Route>
        </div>
    );
```

I would like to define the routes in the PointAndClickGame.tsx files in order to navigate between base_path/, base_path/gameinfo, base_path/gamefinish (where base_path is the path taken from the App.tsx route).

How can this be achieved?